# Using Visual Studio 2008 DBPro to convert database from Sql 2005 to Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-dbpro

I have a DBPro database project that was created for Sql 2005. I am trying to build this on a different environment, with Sql 2008, and I am getting the following error:
`MSBUILD : Build error TSD158: An unsupported target database version was encountered.`
I couldn't find much on this error, and I am unclear what is the conflict. I have tried to change the buildversion element in the database project from 9.0.21022.8 to 10.0.0.0 but that didn't make any difference. I am out of ideas. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target SQL Server 2008, don't you need some GDR update?  See http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/11/25/visual-studio-team-system-2008-database-edition-gdr-rtm.aspx

Also, it might be easier to take your database, restore it on SQL Server 2008 (and let the database upgrade the database itself).  Then just start a new project where you suck down the schema.  But I still think you'll need the GDR in order to do that.